# Почему if не хочет работать правильно (отметил место комментом в коде)

Tags: java

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    HashMap<String, String> passports = new HashMap<>();
    passports.put("63 06 123456", "Иванов Иван Иваныч");

    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Введите искомое ФИО или номер паспорта");
        String input = reader.readLine().trim();


        if (Pattern.compile("[0-9]{2}\\s[0-9]{2}\\s[0-9]{6}").matcher(input).matches()) {
            if (passports.containsKey(input)) {
                System.out.println("Номер паспорта: " + input + " есть в базе принадлежит: " + passports.get(input));
            } else {
                System.out.println("Данного номера, нет в базе данных" + "\n"
                        + "Пожалуйста введите ФИО чтобы добавить владельца в базу или 0 для выхода");
                String newSnm = reader.readLine().trim();
                if (newSnm.equals("0")) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (Pattern.compile("[А-ЯЁ&&[^ЪЬЫ]]{1}[а-яё]+\\s[А-ЯЁ&&[^ЪЬЫ]]{1}[а-яё]+\\s" +
                        "[А-ЯЁ&&[^ЪЬЫ]]{1}[а-яё]+$").matcher(newSnm).matches()) {
                    passports.put(input, newSnm);
                    System.out.println("ФИО и номер паспорта добавлены в базу");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Неверно введено ФИО");
                }
            }
        } else if (Pattern.compile("[А-ЯЁ&&[^ЪЬЫ]]{1}[а-яё]+\\s[А-ЯЁ&&[^ЪЬЫ]]{1}[а-яё]+\\s" +
                "[А-ЯЁ&&[^ЪЬЫ]]{1}[а-яё]+$").matcher(input).matches()) {
            if (passports.containsValue(input)) {
                for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : passports.entrySet()) {
                    String number = entry.getKey();
                    String snm = entry.getValue();
                    if (snm.equals(input)) {
                        System.out.println("ФИО: " + snm + " есть в базе, номера паспорта: " + number);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Данных ФИО, нет в базе данных" + "\n"
                        + "Пожалуйста введите номер паспорта чтобы добавить владельца в базу");
                String newNumber = reader.readLine().trim();
               //Дальше if срабатывает неправильно хотя регулярка верная кидает сразу на else
                if (Pattern.compile("[0-9]{2}\\s[0-9]{2}\\s[0-9]{6}").matcher(input).matches()) {                      
                    passports.put(newNumber, input);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("неверный формат серия/номер паспорта");
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Неправильно введено ФИО или номер паспорта");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Если кажется, что if работает неправильно, то а) неправильное условие, или б) в переменной лежит совсем не то, что думается. Так что отладчик в руки и вперед.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В matcher-e надо заменить `input` на `newNumber`:

`if (Pattern.compile("[0-9]{2}\\s[0-9]{2}\\s[0-9]{6}").matcher(newMember).matches()) // Теперь if работает верно`

На сколько я понял, вы просто скопировали условие из верхней части кода не подумав.
Впредь будьте повнимательнее